# What is the longest self support length a chain one molecule wide can be?

Tags: chemical-engineering, structural-engineering, stresses

[Self-support length is the maximum length of a vertical column of the material (assuming a fixed cross-section) that could suspend its own weight when supported only at the top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_strength) this is an important consideration in the construction of a [space elevator.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/what-is-a-space-elevator)  While it is unlikely a strand one molecule wide to stretch from the surface of the Earth to space, it would be interesting to know what the longest self-support length a chain one molecule wide (single-chain polymers) could be.

A larger molecule gives a larger cross section, but it is also heavier.  Most space elevator concepts are [tapered](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/taper-ratio-for-partial-space-elevator)  to provide additional strength where the load is greatest.

What kind of single-chain polymers can provide the longest self-support length for a column one molecule wide, and what would that self-support length be?

Comment: depends on how you define molecule, some pedants would classify a metal block as a single molecule

Comment: Are you looking for the material that would provide the longest self-support length as well as what that length would be?

Comment: Building on what ratchet freak mentioned, "molecule" may or may not have a useful notion depending on the base material. For most thermoplastics and elastomers you might talk about a single polymer chain. For metals and many ceramics, the notion of molecule is unclear, and nano-metals and nano-ceramics behave very differently than in bulk!

Comment: @TrevorArchibald Yes, "the material that would provide the longest self-support length as well as what that length would be"

Comment: I am not putting limits on the definition of a molecule for this question. The Wikipedia article [Molecule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecule) notes that the definition is not always strict.  If you believe that a supportable definition makes more sense to answer this question, included it, along with support for your definition. I am far from an expert and do not want to instil artificial boundary's.

Comment: Well, a molecule can be arbitrarily wide - take a single "sheet" of graphene, and also arbitrarily thick (take some of the polymers that form branching chains). I guess if you limited this to single-chain polymers, the question would be more answerable.

Comment: Imposing boundaries is often the only way to solve problems in the engineering world. The view that such boundaries are "artificial" is somewhat naive; it is the engineer's experience, education, etc. that allows her to *choose appropriate boundaries*. The less bounded your question, the more theoretical in nature, and the farther it wanders from our scope—keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Updated per @SF. suggestion to "single-chain polymers"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_acetylenic_carbon